# windows 8 Scrollbar in Scrollview by touching not visible

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

In my app I have a ScrollViewer in which I present Items in a StackPanel. When I scroll it with mouse, the vertical scrollbar sit visible. When I scroll this via finger touch, the vertical Scrollbar is unvisible. Is it possible to show my vertical Scrollbar in touch mode? In the following my xaml-code:

```
    <ScrollViewer Width="580"
                  Height="580"
                  Visibility="Visible"
                  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                  HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled"
                  ZoomMode="Disabled">  
            <StackPanel x:Name="viewPanel"
                Background="Transparent"
                Orientation="Vertical"
                Width="Auto"
                Height="Auto"/> 
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will In touch mode, a slimmer scroll indicator is displayed.  This is by design.  You will have to override the ScrollViewer template if you want different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try using VerticleScrollMode="Enabled"